# Data Cleaning python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Below are some of the car info collected from the website while scraping in python.

```
Maruti Suzuki A-Star [2008-2012]Vxi
Hyundai Xcent [2014-2017]SX 1.2 (O)
Ford Figo [2010-2012]Duratorq Diesel Titanium...
Honda CR-V [2009-2013]2.4 AT
Maruti Suzuki Wagon R 1.0 [2010-2013]LXi CNG
Audi A4
Mercedes-Benz E-Class
BMW X3
BMW 3 Serie
```

The task assigned to me is to extract the dates 2010, 2008, 2014 and 2009. These are the ones before the - sign

The pattern i tried to extract them is `[^\-\/\s]\d{4}`.

Output of the above pattern i tried

[image]

Comment: Dates are alway of the form `[####-####]`?

Comment: Try it using a capturing group `\[(\d{4})-\d{4}\]` https://regex101.com/r/l3I7JQ/1

Comment: I only need the date before the  "-"   mark

Answer (score 0):

The negated character class `[^\-\/\s]` matches more than only an opening `[`

To get a more specific match, you could use a capturing group `(\d{4})` for the year.

```
\[(\d{4})-\d{4}\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3I7JQ/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eTRuel)

To match only dates starting with 20:

```
\[(20\d{2})-\d{4}\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UgoZgI/1)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\[(20\d{2})-\d{4}\]"

test_str = ("Maruti Suzuki A-Star [2008-2012]Vxi\n\n"
    "Hyundai Xcent [2014-2017]SX 1.2 (O)\n\n"
    "Ford Figo [2010-2012]Duratorq Diesel Titanium...\n\n"
    "Honda CR-V [2009-2013]2.4 AT\n\n"
    "Maruti Suzuki Wagon R 1.0 [2010-2013]LXi CNG\n\n"
    "Audi A4\n\n"
    "Mercedes-Benz E-Class\n\n"
    "BMW X3\n\n"
    "BMW 3 Serie\n\n\n"
    "Honda CR-V [1909-2013]2.4 AT")


print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['2008', '2014', '2010', '2009', '2010']
```